# Suggested lightweight key-value store for distributing state between many hosts

Tags: database

I'm looking for key-val store that will be used to share some state between multiple hosts.

Goal: 
- Achive high availability for limited set of data, that need to be accesible on every host/node

Requirements:

- put/get/incr/decr operations
- simple numeric data - int/float values, nothing more, no JSON, blobs and so on
- full copy of dataset on every node or automated failure tolerance
- automatic adding/removing of hosts with no need to reconfigure application
- small dataset - only a few megabytes of shared data
- node traffic is load balanced with user-to-node sticking, so only one node at once will - change data related to users that are sticked to that node. This will only change on node failure, but constraint of one master for a set of keys will be keeped, so many readers, one master for own small dataset
- multiple small VM instances will be used, so it should be lightweight in terms of required memory
- automated operation - configure once and forget

I've looked at Riak and CouchDB, but they look like too complicated and too heavy

Any suggestions?